Wie kann man bestimmen, welcher Kasus auf eine Nomen-Präposition-Verbindung folgt?
Ich habe heute einen Satz gesehen, der die folgende Nomen-Präposition-Nomen-Verbindung hatte:

...die Zahlungen an der Frau...*

Und es ist mir aufgefallen, dass ich nicht wusste, wieso auf Zahlung + an der Dativ folgt.  Zudem wusste ich nicht, wie man so was im Allgemeinen bestimmen würde.
Zuerst habe ich „Zahlung" im Duden nachgeschlagen, aber die Information über welcher Kasus folgt war nicht vorhanden.  Danach habe ich einfach das Thema gegoogelt, und zwar habe ich diesen PDF gefunden, aber „Zahlung" steht nicht in der Liste. Theoretisch könnte ich noch eine Liste suchen, aber wenn das für jedes Nomen machen müsste, könnte es umständlich werden.
Ich weiß, dass man sich den richtigen Kasus einfach merken muss, aber woher weiß man, welcher Kasus richtig ist?  In meinem Wörterbüch steht es auch nicht.  Kommt es von der Verb-Präposition-Verbindung?  Das heißt, dass in diesem Fall man zuerst „zahlen an" suchen sollte und danach den Kasus auf die Nomen-Präposition-Nomen-Verbindung extrapolieren?  (Aber mein Wörterbuch sagt leider auch nicht, welche Präposition auf „zahlen an" folgen würde).
*es scheint, dass dieser Satz, der nicht meiner ist, falsch ist.  Nichtdestotrotz würde es mich interessieren, ob es einen Weg gibt, zu wissen, welcher Kasus auf eine Nomen-Präposition-Verbindung folgt...

Es muss aber die Zahlungen an die Frau heißen, denn der verbale Ausdruck lautet etwas an jemanden zahlen.

Das habe ich gedacht!  Daher meine Verwirrung und der Anlass, diese Frage zu stellen, weil ich nicht wusste, wieso es so sein sollte.  Dennoch kann man dann immer sagen, dass der Kasus, der auf die Nomen-Präposition-Verbindung folgt, derselbe ist wie der, der auf die Verb-Präposition-Verbindung folgt?  Das wäre hilfreich zu wissen.

Ja. Das ist immer so.

Es gibt (wenigstens meines Wissens) keine solche Liste, aber eine solche Liste würde auch keine Nomen, sondern die Präpositionen, Verben bzw. (in seltenen Fällen) Adjektive enthalten. Diese sind es nämlich (meistens), die einen bestimmten Kasus erfordern.
Es gibt allerdings ein paar einfache Faustregeln, die mit der Herkunft der Kasus zu tun haben. Die (rekonstruierte) indogermanische Ursprache hatte 8 (möglicherweise 9) Kasus und die sind im Laufe der Zeit immer weiter zusammengefallen, sodaß ein Kasus mittlerweile mehrere Funktionen abdeckt, die dann durch Präpositionen markiert werden müssen. Die deutsche Sprache ist da, verglichen mit anderen indogermanischen Sprachen (Englisch, Französisch, Spanisch, ...) ziemlich konservativ, indem sie noch 4 Kasus hat, andererseits haben die slawischen Sprachen 6 (manche sogar 7), ähnlich dem Latein.
Kurzer Exkurs: Was ist ein Kasus?
Generell gilt, daß Kasus bestimmte Relationen ausdrücken, in die ein Nomen gebracht wird: manche Sprachen, zB. modernes Französisch oder Englisch, unterscheiden da gar nicht, andere wiederum (zB. Altfranzösich, Altokzitanisch) nur zwischen "Objekt" (Kasus obliquus) und "Subjekt" (Nominativ, bzw. Kasus rectus), während etwa Sprachen der finnisch-ugrischen Sprachgruppe eine Vielzahl von Fällen haben (Ungarisch zB über 20), dafür aber praktisch ohne Präpositionen auskommen.
Hier ein Beispiel:
Wenn man auf Deutsch ausdrücken will, daß mit Hilfe von etwas etwas geschieht, dann muß das mit einer Präposition ausgedrückt werden:

Ich schlage mit dem Hammer auf den Nagel.

Manche Sprachen haben dafür dafür einen eigenen Fall, den sogenannten Instrumentalis, der genau diesen Sachverhalt ausdrückt. Nehmen wir an, Deutsch hätte so einen Fall und er würde mit "-u" markiert, dann würde man sagen:

Ich schlage Hammeru auf den Nagel.

Wir könnten uns die Präposition "mit" (und auch den Artikel, der den Dativ anzeigt) sparen.
Deutsch liegt da, wie gesagt, in der Mitte mit seinen 3 Objektkasus, die aber alle mehrere Funktionen erfüllen, welche dann mit Präpositionen angezeigt werden.
Nach diesem kurzen Exkurs nun die Faustregeln/wichtigsten Funktionen für Deutsch:

Genitiv
Die wenigsten Objekte sind im Genitiv. Seine hauptsächlichste Verwendung ist es, Besitz- und Bestandteilverhältnisse (Genitivus partitivus) anzuzeigen:


Der Hund des Besitzers
ein Teil des Ganzen


Dativ
Der Dativ hat Funktionen des früheren Ablativus (Frage: woher?) und des Instrumentalis (Frage: womit?) übernommen. Außerdem bezeichnet er den Nutznießer einer Handlung ("Dativus commodi", beachte, daß "Nutznießer" hier im übertragenen Sinne auch das Gegenteil bedeuten kann, wenn die Handlung Schaden anrichtet). Bei Präpositionen des Ortes bezeichnet er einen Ort (siehe auch Akkusativ).

VORSICHT: Solche Relationen werden im Englischen oft (aber eben nicht immer deckungsgleich) mit "indirect object" ausgedrückt und Deutsch Lernenden wird dann oft von englischsprachigen Lehrern "indirect object=Dativ, direct object=Akkusativ" eingebleut. Das ist falsch und führt nur zur Verwirrung! Diese "Regel" hat so viele Ausnahmen, daß man sie besser ganz vergißt und es gleich richtig lernt.

Ich schenke dem Beschenkten etwas.
Du kommst aus dem Wald.
Ich bin in der Stadt.


Akkusativ
Der Akkusativ hat von allen Objektfällen die meisten Funktionen: er drückt das Ziel (Frage: wen oder was?) bzw. Mittel (Frage: wodurch?) einer Handlung aus. Präpositionen, die das ausdrücken, sind zB. "durch", "für", "gegen", "ohne", etc..


Ich schenke dem Beschenkten das Geschenk.

Außerdem drückt er mit Präpositionen des Ortes eine Richtung (Frage: wohin?) aus. Beachte aber, daß Herkunft nicht als Richtung sondern Ort betrachtet wird und deshalb Dativ verlangt!

Ich gehe in den Norden. (Richtung, Akkusativ)
ABER: Ich komme aus dem Norden. (Ort, Dativ)
Ich gehe um den Baum (herum).
Durch das Fahrrad komme ich schnell herum.

Daneben kann der Akkusativ eine Gleichsetzung ausdrücken.

Er nannte ihn ein Genie.

Außerdem gibt es den sogenannten "absoluten Akkusativ", das sind Konstruktionen, die weder durch ein Verb, noch eine Präposition oder ein Adjektiv verlangt werden und die auch keine richtigen Objekte sind:

Ich stand da wie erstarrt, den Mund vor Staunen offen, ...

Würde man daraus ein herkömmliches Objekt machen, so müßte es im Dativ stehen:

Ich stand da wie erstarrt und mit vor Staunen offenem Mund.

oder, aus Schillers "Bürgschaft":

Zu Dionys, dem Tyrannen, schlich,
Damon, den Dolch im Gewande,

"Den Dolch" ist ein solcher Akkusativus absolutus, der durch einen Dativus locativus ("wo? "im Gewande") ergänzt wird. "-e" ist die (mittlerweile veraltende) Dativmarkierung, die heute nur noch in erstarrten Wendungen ("zu Hause", "zu Buche stehen", "im Wege eines ...", etc.) gebräuchlich ist.
